# qual a melhor forma de criar elementos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for(var i=0; i< numTotalPerguntasDig; i++){

strInterface +=

            "<ul>"+
            "<li class=\"col-md-2 \">"+
            "   <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco form-control\">"+
            "       <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>" +
            "       <span class=\"texto-btn\">/span>"+
            "   </button>"+
            "</li>"+*/
            "<li class=\"col-md-2 \">"+"<input type='text' class='info-1 form-control' style='width: 100%' value='"+arraySeq[i]+"'/>"+"</li>"+
            "<li class=\"col-md-6 \">"+"<input type='text' class='info-2 form-control'  placeholder='Digite'/>"+"</li>"+
            "<li class=\"col-md-2 \">"+
            "   <select class='info-3 form-control'>"+
            "       <option value='1'>1</option>"+
            "   </select>"+
            "</li>"+
            "<li class=\"col-md-2\">"+
                "<button class='btnadd btn btn-danger btn-sm form-control' value='x'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span> </button>"+
            "</li>"+
            "</ul>";


menu.append(strInterface);

}
```

`append` ou `createElement`?

Qual a melhor forma ou a forma mais visual para se entender o código em uma futura manutenção?

Comment: olha, as duas são bem legíveis, o `createElement` vai requerer mais algumas linhas, mas nada problemático, em todo caso, o maior problema acima é esta concatenação de strings, neste caso o uso de uma Template Engine vai tornar o seu codigo bem mais limpo.

Comment: você tem alguma indicação de template engine? angular.js pode ser usado como uma template engine?

Comment: Denali, postei um exemplo com o [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com), a vantagem dele é ser independente do jQuery, então pode ser usado com qual quer biblioteca. você tambem pode usar o [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io), [JsRender](http://www.jsviews.com).

Comment: Denali, acredito que seja possivel, mas acredito que o template engine do AngularJS seja bastante dependente da sua estrutura, usar ele de forma stand-alone pode ser bem complicado, então se está a usar AngularJS, use a Template Engine do AngularJS, senão escolha uma outra de sua preferencia,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

como eu disse, o melhor é não fazer o uso de concatenação de strings, segue um exemplo com o uso do [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) (Template Engine).

Note que é possível adicionar laços e condições dentro do seu template. outro ponto importante a ser notado, é que o elemento `<script type="text/template"></script>` é ignorado pelo browser na hora de renderizar, por tanto ele será usado apenas pelo script (sem impacto no carregamento inicial da pagina).

As duas grandes vantagens desta abordagem é deixar o script limpo, assim como o conteudo do template é bem mais próximo do HTML final, sem caracteres de escape ("\"") ou concatenações ("" + variável + "").

```js
var model = {
  perguntas: ["Banana", "Maça", "Pera"]
};

var menu = $("#menu");
var source  = $("#tmlMenu").html();
var tmlMenu = Handlebars.compile(source);
var menus = $.parseHTML(tmlMenu(model));

menu.append(menus);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<div id="menu">

</div>

<script id="tmlMenu" type="text/template">
  {{#each perguntas}}
  <ul>
    <li class="col-md-2 ">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco form-control">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="texto-btn"></span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-2 "><input type='text' class='info-1 form-control' style='width: 100%' value='{{this}}'/></li>
    <li class="col-md-6 "><input type='text' class='info-2 form-control'  placeholder='Digite'/></li>
    <li class="col-md-2 ">
      <select class='info-3 form-control'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-2">
      <button class='btnadd btn btn-danger btn-sm form-control' value='x'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Se me permite fazer o advogado do diabo aqui, em que sentido exatamente a concatenação de strings é pior do que carregar e usar uma biblioteca externa, que por sua vez provavelmente fará suas próprias concatenações de string (além de muito mais coisas)?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, até concordo que para o exemplo acima o uso de uma Template Engine pode ser um exagero, especialmente se a única parte do sistema que necessite desta abordagem seja o menu, outro ponto, esta blibioteca não necessariamente usa concatenação de strings, ela pode fazer substituições usando Regex como no no [exemplo]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/378001/4470747). Para algo mais simples podemos simplesmente combinar esta função de formatação com a resposta do Wallace.

Answer (score 6):

Usando *jQuery* é possível criar um elemento de uma forma que particularmente eu considero mais elegante, porém cada elemento precisa ser criado individualmente.

```js
div = $("<div>", {
  "class" : "novo_elemento segunda_classe",
  id : "elemento_teste",
  height : "150px",
  width : "200px"
});

$("body").html(div);
```

```css
#elemento_teste{
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.novo_elemento{
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Com esse método você pode adicionar esse elemento criado utilizando `.append()`, `.prepend()`, `.appendTo()`, `.prependTo()` e `.html()`.

Assim você passa a ter uma declaração elegante do seu elemento e pode aplica-lo da maneira que mais considerar adequada.

Um ponto "negativo" de criar um elemento dessa forma é a necessidade de criar individualmente cada elemento o que torna mais trabalhosa a criação inicial, porém, isso também é um ponto positivo, pois te garante também maior controle sobre cada um deles e possibilita o reuso dos mesmo, facilitando assim a manutenção do seu código.

Apenas como um exemplo de como isso pode te ajudar a deixar seu código com uma melhor manutenção você pode por exemplo criar modelos de elementos e a partir daí modificar apenas suas particularidades

### Exemplo:

```js
inputDefault = $("<input>",{
    "class" : "input",
    name : "Input",
    type : "text"
});

inputAge = inputDefault.clone().attr({
    name : "age"+inputDefault.attr("name"),
    type : "number",
    placeholder: "Idade"
});

inputName = inputDefault.clone().attr({
    name : "name"+inputDefault.attr("name"),
    placeholder: "Nome"
});

$(".inputs").html(inputName)
 .append("<br>")
 .append(inputAge);
```

```css
.inputs{
    background: #f0f0a0;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs"></div>
```

Comment: Erlon, acredito que a duvida do Denali é sobre manter o código limpo e com manutenção mais simples, e montar o menu criando todas as tags desta forma não vá deixar o código muito legível e muito menos facilitar uma manutenção futura...

Comment: De acordo com o exemplo que eu postei ele pode criar modelos de itens do menu, e ir modificando cada item de acordo com a necessidade, só seria interessante ter bem definido um esqueleto e um padrão. O trabalho maior estaria em definir e criar o esqueleto, a partir daí até criar um menu com 500 itens (hipérbole) não seria uma tarefa tão árdua e dolorosa.

Comment: No HTML dele a única coisa que muda estando no for é o `value` do `input class="info-1...`, então até dinamizar esse valor dentro de um laço fica mais fácil com um esqueleto definido. Mas sua resposta também foi boa @TobyMosque.

Comment: Erlon, assumi que o exemplo dele era apenas um exemplo, e que a duvida do mesmo era quanto a legibilidade na hora de montar um conteúdo dinâmico client-side, apesar de concorda que no exemplo acima a sua reposta seja legível e de facil manutenção, porem o script pode se tornar bastante complexo dependendo do modelo de dados. e não me leve a mal, apesar da critica eu achei a sua resposta boa, tanto que dei +1 nela.

Comment: Concordo, pensando em performance final também eu já mandaria um html pronto pro _client-side_ se for um menú absurdamente extenso isso pode prejudicar o carregamento da página. Mas ainda bem que ele obteve uma solução para seu problema, parabéns pela sugestão. :D

Comment: Montar o HTML no servidor nem sempre é a opção com melhor desempenho, lembre-se que o template pode ser um arquivo separado no servidor e ser armazenado no cliente usando o localStorage, assim permitindo a reutilização e diminuição do tráfego de dados.

Comment: Eu sei, mas na grande maioria dos casos apenas exibir um HTML pronto traz diferenças significativas.

Comment: estou montando o menu dinâmico inteiramente no client-side. será que há algum problema? depende da máquina do usuário também, não é?

Comment: Tem alguns aspectos a serem avaliados, a máquina do usuário é um dos fatores, mas antes disso como você monta esse menu no _client-side_, procura alguma ferramenta de desempenho pra conferir como está o da usa página, assim você terá como avaliar qual a melhor solução para seu caso. Como o @TobyMosque falou existem situações em que o _server-side_ cause lentidão por muita carga de dados ou por baixa qualidade do servidor de hospedagem.

Answer (score 2):

Com o jQuery é possível criar o elemento a definir seus atributos de forma dinâmica da seguinte forma:

```
$('<button/>', {
    class: 'btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco form-control',
    name: 'btn-login',
    text: 'Login'
}).appendTo('#form');
```

Prático e visualmente elegante.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma é utilizando a tag `script` com um `type` diferente.

Exemplo:

```js
$(function()
{
   $('#container').append($('#tpl').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="tpl">
      <div class="x">
        <p class='y'>Olá mundo</p>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Isso acontece porque o conteúdo dentro de `script` com o type `text/template` não é interpretado como javascript!

Comment: Essa eu não conhecia! +1

Comment: Wallace, o HTML dela tem um pequeno trecho que não é estatico.

Comment: Nesse caso podemos utilizar o undescore.js, para poder fazer o parser desse template enviando dados.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é usar um texto pronto, acrescentar no DOM, e depois mudar só o que você precisa. Assumindo jQuery:

```
var item = "<li class=\"col-md-2 \">"+
            "   <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco form-control\">"+
            "       <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>" +
            "       <span class=\"texto-btn\">/span>"+
            "   </button>"+
            "</li>"+*/
            "<li class=\"col-md-2 \">"+"<input type='text' class='info-1 form-control' style='width: 100%' value=''/>"+"</li>"+
            "<li class=\"col-md-6 \">"+"<input type='text' class='info-2 form-control'  placeholder='Digite'/>"+"</li>"+
            "<li class=\"col-md-2 \">"+
            "   <select class='info-3 form-control'>"+
            "       <option value='1'>1</option>"+
            "   </select>"+
            "</li>"+
            "<li class=\"col-md-2\">"+
                "<button class='btnadd btn btn-danger btn-sm form-control' value='x'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span> </button>"+
            "</li>";

for(var i=0; i< numTotalPerguntasDig; i++){
    var elemento = $(item);
    elemento.find(".info-1.form-control").val(arraySeq[i]);
    menu.append(elemento);
}
```

Assim a estrutura do HTML a ser inserido está evidente, e a concatenação só é feita uma única vez. A parte variável de fato ocorre direto no DOM (i.e. deve ser bem eficiente).